# Green screen while starting up MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, startup, graphics

For last two three days I have been experiencing this problem. My MacBook Pro looks like this while booting up:

[image]

But after running for 30 or 40 min this thing goes normal, no problem at all after that time. A strange thing is it happens when there is a long gap between successive booting up of it.

I have tried resetting NVRAM and SMC but no luck.

My MacBook config is as follows:

macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015), 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5, Memory 8GB 1867 MHz DDR3, Graphics Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536MB

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a hardware issue, probably GPU. Run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) and something GPU heavy like [Unigine Heaven](https://benchmark.unigine.com/heaven) and see if it exhibits any issues. In any case, I'd say take it into an Apple store and explain your situation.

Comment: Ran Apple Diagnostics.. No issues Found.
Also ran Unigin Heaven, didn't face any issue

Comment: Don't know what to say then for sure. I'd still take it into an Apple Store and see what they say, hopefully a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

The place I'm working at now is a cold and high humidity office and I have the same issue: unsaturated colors and green display over dark interfaces for about 20 minutes. This could be the reason.

Comment: I didn't take it to the store. it only happens when the MacBook is shut down for a while. after booting up, it takes 15 -20 min to clear up. otherwise no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I figured out how to get it to normal at least for one using time before having to do this workaround the next day again (I think... I just figured that out today with the advice of another forum).

**Go to Display Options to change to another resolution of your choice - problem's gone. Change it back - still gone.**

I will see tomorrow if it's still gone. If not, I'll try to set it to a different resolution and see the day after tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure, I will always have to do this workaround till I finally have to get my MacBook Pro fixed (for, I think, a lot of money).